# Copy filtered data back to same data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter dataframe and copy back the result to the same dataframe. Basically want to ignore all rows which doesn't fit my criteria.

df = df[df.temperature>30]  #I only want data/rows with temperature column above 30.

When I print df I get desired result but I get following error when I further work on the df.

Exception has occurred: KeyError
0

Comment: If you got the desired df and then getting an error, please post the code for which you are getting the error

Comment: Filtering a dataframe retains the original indexes but with indexes corresponding to the values qualifying your condition in temperature column. 

You can use the .reset_index(drop=True) method after you filter your df.

Comment: You can also use .iloc[index, :] to select specific rows without having to reindex.

Comment: df.reset_index(drop=True) did not fix the issue.
test = df['temperature'][0]     #I get error here.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

Thanks Sarath Gadde for the hint!